# c# call constructor by assigning

Tags: c#, constructor

can i call a constructor by assigning?
this is my class

```
public class Person
{
public string sName;
public string sAge;

public Person (string sPerson)
{
//in sPerson i have Name and Age separate from ,
sName=sPerson.split(',')[0];
sAge=sPerson.split(',')[1];
}
```

in main code i need valorize my object but i cannot call constructor, there's a way to call constructor like this?

```
Person myObject = newPerson();
myPerson = sPeson;
```

}

Comment: Do you mean `Person myObject = myPerson;`?

Comment: Is `newPerson` a typo (`new Person`)? There is no parameterless constructor. What are `sPeson` and `myPerson`? Wat does *valorize my object* mean?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can provide a [copy-constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173116.aspx) that takes another `Person`:

```
public Person (Person otherPerson)
{
    sName = otherPerson.sName;
    sAge = otherPerson.sAge;
}
```

You can call it in this way:

```
Person myObject = new Person(sPerson);
```